# How to solve this differential equation using ode23?

Tags: matlab, system, simulink, ode

What I have here is a gear system I need to simulate using
MATLAB and Simulink.

[image: Gear system]

To do that, firstly I need to get the differential equation for this
rotation (gear) system. I **think** I managed to do so and it is as
follows

```
iT1 = J * theta2''+D * theta2'+K * theta2,
```

where `J = i^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2` (also, `i` is the gear ratio; `i = theta1/theta2 = N2/N1 = Tn2 / Tn1 = T2/T1`).

Now I need to solve this second-order differential equation using
ode23 in MATLAB. The problem is, I don't know any initial conditions,
nor do I know how to get them from this particular system e.g. `y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1` Can I still solve this particular problem without the
initial conditions, or do I make the initial conditions up...? In case
anyone needs it the parameters of my problem are as follows:

```
N2 = 90, N1 = 36, 
Jn1 = 0.5 Nms^2/rad, Jn2 = 0.8 Nms^2/rad, 
J2 = 2 Nms^2/rad, D = 8 Nms/rad, K = 5 Nm/rad
```

The differential equation should look like this for `y=theta2` and
`x=T1`

```
    y''+1.3502y'+0.8439y = 0.4219x
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could you describe the mechanical system somewhat more? There is some gear assembly on one side, a dampened spring on the other, how are they connected? Are you looking for the long-term behavior like a limit cycle or some other asymptote where the influence of any initial condition has become negligible? // The question might be off-topic here, scicomp.SE or physics.SE could be more appropriate, check their scope descriptions. Here you ideally would have to present some code that you have problems with.

Comment: I imagined this particular system as a gearbox with a flywheel on the second shaft. What I want to do is to simulate the output of this particular system for a step input and sine wave input. My output should be the position of the second shaft, in radians.

Answer (score 0):

as I don't know about your education on differential equations, first of all:
The initial, or boundary conditions (in this case initial) conditions as my professor always stated, make up the solution since any ode is solved by integration and without those conditions a ode cannot be solved - actually.

But as this looks you seem to have a second order ode, so you can determine a solution for it which will describe the system itself.

I don't know how to write latex here but a quick example:

Given the simplest ode

dy/dx = y

This can be solved with the splitting of the variables

1/y * dy = dx

with integration

ln(y) = x + C_0 -> y = exp(x) + C
with C being exp(c_0)

This should be possible with your ode. Take a look at the symbolic math toolbox in matlab or read about odes (I don't have the time but it seems to me that your ode should be solvable analytically - search for: solve second order differential equation analytically).

Some words about the C, actually this is where your boundary or inital condition would end up. With the above example this could be the grwoth of a population, then C would be your initial population size. Without initial conditions you can only say how the system would evolve but not which state it will be in at a specific point in time.

Another word: Actually your ode to me seems to be the quite well known harmonic oszillator. You will find plenty of stuff for this.

Maybe you want to determine the eigenvalues of the system to determine if is stable for any frequence, then your equation has to be of the form x'' + d*x' + k*x = 0 (has to be zero) - this will end up in solving the characteristic equation (a second order polynome in lambda) in my example I took a spring oszillator but you can fir this to rotation.

If you finally end up having initial values, for solving via ode23 you have to make it a system of differential equations (google it or take a look at a math book) and then solve this system. In MATLAB write a function that returns the gradients of the system of differential equations like

```
function grads = calc_grads(immediate_vals)

% calculate all the n grads - here two - determined by the ode
grads(1) = ...
grads(2) = ...
end
```

this function must be callable by ode23.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look something like this

```
% parameters
N2  = 90;
N1  = 36;
Jn1 = 0.5;
Jn2 = 0.8;
J2  = 2;
D   = 8;
K   = 5;
J   = (N2/N1)^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2;

% define the system
sys = ss([0 1; -K/J -D/J], [0; N2/(N1*J)], [1 0], 0);

% initial state: (position, velocity) [rad; rad/s]
x0 = [0.1; 0];

% define the time span
t = linspace(0, 15, 10000)';

% define the input step
T1 = zeros(length(t), 1);
T1(t>=1) = 1;

% compute the system step response at once
theta1 = lsim(sys, T1, t, x0);

% compute the system response as aggregate of the forced and unforced
% temporal evolutions
theta2 = lsim(sys, T1, t, [0; 0]) + initial(sys, x0, t);

% plot results
figure('color', 'white');
hold on;
yyaxis left;
plot(t, T1, '-.', 'linewidth', 2);
ylabel('[N]');
yyaxis right;
plot(t, theta1, 'linewidth', 3);
plot(t, theta2, 'k--');
xlabel('t [s]');
ylabel('[rad]');
grid minor;
legend({'$T_1$', '$\theta_1$', '$\theta_2$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex',...
       'location', 'southeast');
hold off;
```

What I want to know now is how would I simulate the output for a sine wave function? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, "The MATLAB ODE solvers only solve first-order equations. You must rewrite higher-order ODEs as an equivalent system of first-order equations."[1] That is to say, to solve a second-order equation like:

```
iT1 = J*theta2'' + D*theta2' + K*theta2
```

you should rewrite it as: [1,2]

```
Y = [  Y_1  ] = [ theta2  ]
    [  Y_2  ]   [ theta2' ]

d/dt Y = [             Y_2              ]
         [ -1/J * (D*Y_2 + K*Y_1 - iT1) ]
```

where `t` is the independent variable. The definition `d/dt Y_1 = Y_2` may look tautological, but it is necessary to unify the otherwise unrelated (as far as the machine knows) variables `Y_1` and `Y_2`.

Regarding initial values, yes, they are necessary; you must know the initial value of vector `Y`.

Please bear in mind that `ode23()` is a numerical solver (one among many MATLAB has to offer) that finds use with many highly complicated equations, especially those which cannot be analytically solved. If you want analytical solutions, which would not require initial conditions to be fixed beforehand, `ode23()` is not the right tool for the job; the Symbolic Math Toolbox, as highlighted in the previous answer, might be more useful in that case. Sooner or later, however, you will probably end up needing to define initial conditions. See [3] for details.

[1] https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html (See section "Higher-Order ODEs")

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_of_order

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem